# I want to update 50000 records in DB, taking 2 minutes, Anybody with Better Solution?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

```
var EffectedRows = from rfvl in FieldValuesList where rfvl.Record_RecordId == RecordId select rfvl;

foreach (var item in EffectedRows)  
{
    var feature = (from RGDF in ctx.FieldValues where  RGDF.RecordId == item.RecordId select RGDF).Single();
    { 
        feature.Amount = item.Amount;
        feature.Boolean = item.Boolean;

    };
}

ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: How should anyone post a "better" solution, when you show absoliutely nothing about your structure. Anyway you can´t do much here: if you want to update 50.000 items, you have to iterate 50.00 features and update them. Maybe there´s some bulk-update available, but that depends on your DBMS.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: If the FieldValuesList contains 50000 items, you might not want to execute the .Single() query 50000 times, you could either use direct sql updates within a transaction scope or materialize the entire FieldValues collection to memory with one round trip to the database.

Comment: Sql server Database I am using

Comment: I have EffectedRows List with 50000 REcords and ctx.FieldValues Table with Million Records I just want to update the Table Data using EffectedRows items.(Amount and Boolean)

Comment: It seems you have only one single RecordID, in your EffectedRows collection.The entire EffectedRows collection seems to be pretty useless. Actually you do a Join from FieldValuesList to FieldValues. But you don't use an SQL-Join.
If RecordID is a parameter or constant, then item.RecordID is also, then any of your "Single()" calls will return always the same element, so you update the same element 50.000 times. That's kind of nonsense. You are lucky, you save it only once. Your entire runtime is taken for the 50.000 Single()-requests, not for the SaveChanges. This effects only one entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see : [Performance issue when performing operations on entity objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59624767/performance-issue-when-performing-operations-on-entity-objects/59625377#59625377)

```
var EffectedRows = (from rfvl in FieldValuesList 
                   where rfvl.Record_RecordId == RecordId 
                   select rfvl)
                   .ToList();


foreach (var item in EffectedRows)  
{
    //this is expensive its a call to the db on each loop
    var feature  = (from RGDF in ctx.FieldValues 
                    where  RGDF.RecordId == item.RecordId select RGDF
                    ).Single()

    feature.Amount = item.Amount;
    feature.Boolean = item.Boolean;  
}

ctx.SaveChanges();
```

---

```
var EffectedRows = (from rfvl in FieldValuesList 
                   where rfvl.Record_RecordId == RecordId 
                   select rfvl)
                   .ToList();

var ids = EffectedRows.select(x.RecordId)
var features  = ctx.FieldValues.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.RecordId).ToList();

//below is in mem only now.
foreach (var item in EffectedRows)  
{
    feature = features.where(x=>x.RecordId == item.RecordId).Single()
    feature.Amount = item.Amount;
    feature.Boolean = item.Boolean;  
}

//you could consider batchs... this will so help... but my guess is this will be like 13 secs or less
//you can get down to about 4 secs max if you try harder with batching
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: @deskCode_1991 awesome, to be honest im surprised that it was only taking 2min, out of interest how long does it take now.

Comment: Its taking 3 seconds now